# Wiki page creation similar to Trac, any?

Tags: wiki

I want to create private wiki pages and want to publish the same only for inetrnal.
Can any list the easiest way to do this.

Some are Twiki, mediawiki, intodit.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of existing questions about Wiki systems, for instance:

- [Which wiki to use after MediaWiki?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822038/which-wiki-to-use-after-mediawiki)
- [What's the best open source wiki platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541675/whats-the-best-open-source-wiki-platform)
- [Wiki Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211276/wiki-evaluation)

And more, see the "Related" sidebar on the right.

My personal favorite is [DokuWiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/). It stores its data in plain, human readable (and human writable) files instead of a database, which I think is very cool and a definitive advantage. And it runs on about any web server, since it's in PHP. And it has quite a flexible user access control.